# Combine latest value of observables AFTER every emission from source observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a source Observable (actually a Subject) and when that Observable emits a value, I need to kick off a load of values that results in 2 more observables being updated, and when that load is done take the value of the source and combine it with the latest values of the 2 "dependent" observables, but only the values from AFTER the source observable emits.  So if the 2 dependent observables have values when the source emits, I need this to wait until the 2 dependents get updates before emitting the latest of all 3 observables.  I've tried using various incantations of withLatestFrom, switchMap, and combineLatest, but nothing is giving me the desired output:

This will emit values in the right shape, but not at the right time, it is using the values from before the SelectExpenseSummary has done its thing and the expenseDetails$ and expenseReceipts$ have updated.

```
      this.editExpenseSubject.pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.active),
         tap(x => this.userStore.dispatch(new SelectExpenseSummary(x))),
         tap(x => this.log.verbose({type: 'ExpensesFeatureComponent:editExpenseSubject:tap', x})),
         withLatestFrom(
          this.expenseDetails$,
          this.expenseReceipts$,
          )
        )
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.log.verbose({type: 'ExpensesFeatureComponent:editExpenseSubject:subscribe', x});
      });
```

This emits a bunch of times, with the last time having the correct values, which would be OK, but emits the wrong shape, it's missing the source observable from the output:

```
      this.editExpenseSubject.pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.active),
         tap(x => this.userStore.dispatch(new SelectExpenseSummary(x))),
         tap(x => this.log.verbose({type: 'ExpensesFeatureComponent:editExpenseSubject:tap', x})),
         switchMap(() =>
            combineLatest(this.expenseDetails$,
            this.expenseReceipts$,
            )
          )
        )
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.log.verbose({type: 'ExpensesFeatureComponent:editExpenseSubject:subscribe', x});
      });
```

This has the right output shape, having all 3 observables, but it never emits anything in the subscribe, I'm guessing because of the use of editExpenseSubject inside:

```
      this.editExpenseSubject.pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.active),
         tap(x => this.userStore.dispatch(new SelectExpenseSummary(x))),
         tap(x => this.log.verbose({type: 'ExpensesFeatureComponent:editExpenseSubject:tap', x})),
         switchMap(x =>
          combineLatest(
            this.editExpenseSubject
            , this.expenseDetails$
            , this.expenseReceipts$
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.log.verbose({type: 'ExpensesFeatureComponent:editExpenseSubject:subscribe', x});
      });
```

Can someone point me to the correct incantation to get what I'm after, preferably with detailed explanation as to why.

---

Update for additional info (I think this gets you through the whole flow):

```
    this.expenseDetails$ = this.expenseStore.pipe(
      select(fromExpenses.getExpenseLines)
    );
    this.expenseReceipts$ = this.expenseStore.pipe(
      select(fromExpenses.getExpenseReceipts)
    );

export const getExpenseLines = createSelector(StateFeatureSelector, x => x.expenseLines);
export const getExpenseReceipts = createSelector(StateFeatureSelector, x => x.expenseReceipts);

export interface State {
  expenseSummaries: Array<IExpenseSummary>;
  expenseLines: Array<IExpenseLine>;
  expenseReceipts: Array<IExpenseReceipt>;
  selectedUser: IDirectReport;
  selectedExpenseSummary: IExpenseSummary;
}


  @Effect() LoadExpenseLines$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<fromExpense.LoadExpenseLines>(fromExpense.ActionTypes.LoadExpenseLines)
    , tap(action => this.log.debug({type: 'ExpenseEffects:LoadExpenseLines$:filtered', action}))
    , mergeMap(x =>
      this.service.getExpenseLines(x && x.payload)
        .pipe(
          tap(receipts => this.log.debug({type: 'ExpenseEffects:getExpenseLines', receipts}))
          , map(lineItems => new fromExpense.SetExpenseLines(lineItems))
        )
    )
  );
  @Effect() LoadExpenseReceipts$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<fromExpense.LoadExpenseReceipts>(fromExpense.ActionTypes.LoadExpenseReceipts)
    , tap(action => this.log.debug({type: 'ExpenseEffects:LoadExpenseReceipts$:filtered', action}))
    , mergeMap(x =>
      this.service.getExpenseReceipts(x && x.payload)
        .pipe(
          tap(receipts => this.log.debug({type: 'ExpenseEffects:getExpenseReceipts', receipts}))
          , map(receipts => new fromExpense.SetExpenseReceipts(receipts))
        )
    )
  );

  @Effect() SelectExpenseSummary$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<fromExpense.SelectExpenseSummary>(fromExpense.ActionTypes.SelectExpenseSummary)
    , tap(action => this.log.debug({type: 'ExpenseEffects:SelectExpenseSummary$:filtered', action}))
    , mergeMap(x =>
        [
          new fromExpense.LoadExpenseLines(x.payload)
          , new fromExpense.LoadExpenseReceipts(x.payload)
        ]
    )
  );

export class SelectExpenseSummary implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.SelectExpenseSummary;
  constructor(public payload: IExpenseSummary) {}
}

export class LoadExpenseLines implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.LoadExpenseLines;
  constructor(public payload: IExpenseSummary) {}
}
export class SetExpenseLines implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.SetExpenseLines;
  constructor(public payload: Array<IExpenseLine>) {}
}

export class LoadExpenseReceipts implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.LoadExpenseReceipts;
  constructor(public payload: IExpenseSummary) {}
}

export class SetExpenseReceipts implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.SetExpenseReceipts;
  constructor(public payload: Array<IExpenseReceipt>) {}
}

export function reducer (state = initialState, action: actions.ActionsUnion): State {
  switch (action.type) {
// ...  other actions cut
    case actions.ActionTypes.SetExpenseLines:
      return {
        ...state,
        expenseLines: action.payload && [...action.payload] || []
      };
    case actions.ActionTypes.SetExpenseReceipts:
      return {
        ...state,
        expenseReceipts: action.payload && [...action.payload] || []
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// from the service class used in the effects

  getExpenseLines(summary: IExpenseSummary): Observable<Array<IExpenseLine>> {
    this.log.debug({type: 'ExpenseService:getExpenseLines', summary, uri: this.detailUri});
    if (summary) {
      return this.http
        .post<Array<IExpenseLine>>(this.detailUri, {ExpenseGroupId: summary.ExpReportNbr})
        .pipe(
          tap(data => this.log.verbose({ type: 'ExpenseService:getExpenseLines:reponse', data }))
        );
    } else {
      this.log.log({ type: 'ExpenseService:getExpenseLines null summary'});
      return of<Array<IExpenseLine>>([])
      .pipe(
        tap(data => this.log.verbose({ type: 'ExpenseService:getExpenseLines:reponse', data }))
      );
    }
  }
  getExpenseReceipts(summary: IExpenseSummary): Observable<Array<IExpenseReceipt>> {
    this.log.debug({type: 'ExpenseService:getExpenseReceipts', summary, uri: this.receiptUri});
    if (summary) {
      return this.http
      .post<Array<IExpenseReceipt>>(this.receiptUri, {ExpenseGroupId: summary.ExpReportNbr})
      .pipe(
        tap(data => this.log.verbose({ type: 'ExpenseService:getExpenseReceipts:reponse', data }))
      );
    } else {
      this.log.log({ type: 'ExpenseService:getExpenseReceipts null summary'});
      return of<Array<IExpenseReceipt>>([])
      .pipe(
        tap(data => this.log.verbose({ type: 'ExpenseService:getExpenseReceipts:reponse', data }))
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I can't deal with the commas at the start of the line style. Can you edit it please? :P

Comment: @AvinKavish lol. I know, it hurts my eyes.

Comment: ugh, is comma placement the new tabs vs spaces?  I guess I could at least be consistent.

Comment: Just FYI for anyone else coming here, I did not find a solution using the above, I ended up reworking it entirely.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going from @Reactgular's assumption :

> You want to take an emitted value from the subject, and then emit from 2 other observables their latest value. With the output being an array of 3 items.
>
> You want the 2 inner observables to fetch new data after the outer observable emits, and you only want their first value.

From there, the operator that comes to mind is `skip` : it skips the number of values you ask to skip and continues afterward.

[I have made a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/agitated-cori-mobyl) for you to see it in action : as you can see, both observables are updated from a single source, and you get only one event, which is the last values of each observable.

related code :

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import {
  delayWhen,
  skip,
  distinctUntilKeyChanged,
  distinctUntilChanged,
  skipUntil,
  switchMap,
  map
} from "rxjs/operators";

const counts = {
  source: 0,
  first: 0,
  second: 0
};

const source$ = new BehaviorSubject("source = " + counts.source);
const first$ = new BehaviorSubject("first = " + counts.first);
const second$ = new BehaviorSubject("second = " + counts.second);

// Allow the source to emit
fromEvent(document.querySelector("button"), "click").subscribe(() => {
  counts.source++;
  source$.next("source = " + counts.source);
});

// When the source emits, the others should emit new values
source$.subscribe(source => {
  counts.first++;
  counts.second++;
  first$.next("first = " + counts.first);
  second$.next("second = " + counts.second);
});

// Final result should be an array of all observables

const final$ = source$.pipe(
  switchMap(source =>
    first$.pipe(
      skip(1),
      switchMap(first =>
        second$.pipe(
          skip(1),
          map(second => [source, first, second])
        )
      )
    )
  )
);

final$.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Comment: sandbox looks promising, I'll try it out shortly.

Comment: @BlackICE sure, if you aren't satisfied with it, please provide a [mcve] with your actual data (well, mocks of it) so that I can work on !

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly....

You want to take an emitted value from the subject, and then emit from 2 other observables their latest value. With the output being an array of 3 items.

You want the 2 inner observables to fetch new data after the outer observable emits, and you only want their first value.

```
 this.editExpenseSubject.pipe(
        switchMap(editExpense =>
            forkJoin(
               this.expenseDetails$.pipe(first()),
               this.expenseReceipts$.pipe(first()),
            ).pipe(
               map(values => ([editExpense, ...values]))
            )
          )
        )
```

You can use a [switchMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) so that it calls subscribe on the inner observable, and use a [forkJoin()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to get the final values. Adding a [first()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html) operator to limit the observables to 1 value. You then use [map()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) to place the outer value back into the results array.

Comment: Initially this looked good, on the first emit I got values from expenseDetails$ and expenseReceipts$ whereas before I was getting empty arrays, but subsequent emits are giving the the values for expenseDetails$ and expenseReceipts$ from the previous source emit.

Comment: @BlackICE can you update your question with the source code that create `this.expenseDetails$` and `this.expenseReceipts$`

Comment: provided code through the entire flow, let me know if I missed anything or you need more.